# AttributeError: 'WindowManager' object has no attribute 'createWindow'

Tags: python, image, opencv, object-detection

Here are the two code blocks:

```
class WindowManager(object):
  def __init__(self, windowName, keypressCallback = None):
    self.keypressCallback = keypressCallback
    self._windowName = windowName
    self._isWindowCreated = False

    @property
    def isWindowCreated(self):
      return self._isWindowCreated
    def createWindow(self):
      cv2.namedWindow(self._windowName)
      self._isWindowCreated = True
    def show(self, frame):
      cv2.imsmhow(self._windowName, frame)
    def destroyWindow(self):
      cv2.destroyWindow(self._windowName)
      self._isWindowCreated = False
    def processEvents(self):
      keycode = cv2.waitKey(1)
      if self.keypressCallback is not None and keycode != -1:
        self.keypressCallback(keycode)

class Cameo(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self._windowManager = WindowManager('Cameo', self.onKeypress)
    self._captureManager = CaptureManager(cv2.VideoCapture(0), self._windowManager, True)

  #Defining the run method:
  def run(self):
    self._windowManager.createWindow()
    while self._windowManager.isWindowCreated:
      self._captureManager.enterFrame()
      frame = self._captureManager.frame
      if frame is not None:
        self._captureManager.exitFrame()
        self._windowManager.processEvents()

  #Define the onKeypress method:
  def onKeypress(self, keycode):
    if keycode == 32:
      self._captureManager.writeImage('screenshot.png')
    elif keycode == 9:
      if not self._captureManager.isWritingVideo:
        self._captureManager.startWritingVideo('screencast.avi')
      else:
        self._captureManager.stopWritingVideo()
    elif keycode == 27:
      self._windowManager.destroyWindow()

#Adding a main block that instatiates and runs cameo
if __name__=="__main__":
  Cameo().run()
```

I am trying to run my code but I keep getting the attribute error even tho the attribute I am calling is defined as part of the classes properties. An answer would be much appreciated.

Comment: please provide a minimal reproducible example. this example contains a lot of irrelevant stuff.

Comment: Post the error as well please. Thanks.

Comment: Here's the main error: AttributeError: 'WindowManager' object has no attribute 'createWindow'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's a simple indentation error.

all your `WindowManager` attributes are defined *inside* your `__init__()` function

(so they are invisible to the rest of your program)